# Service settings

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have a service, written in VB, with some user settings. Two of these are an oauth access / refresh token, and I need to keep storing the new token, so whenever that is updated, I write the settings away again.

Can anyone tell me where those settings are stored on my PC? I can see that the app.exe.config file is not being updated, and it's not being read when I start the service. I don't have a folder in users\username\appdata\local for the service name, nor in roaming, nor in locallow.

I tried using installutil to uninstall and re-install my service, hoping that might cause it to use the settings in app.exec.config, but it did not, it's still trying to use a token that's long out of date from somewhere.

If I paste a new token pair into my app.exe.config, I can see that the service is not reading it. It is reading an old token from when I was last working on it / testing it, and getting an expiry error because I've used a new token pair in a desktop test version of the app.

I seem to be going round and round in circles trying to find where these settings are stored. The annoying thing is that I've had it working, and "sometimes" it will pick up the new token and everything works. But I soon need to install it on the customers PC, and I'm concerned that I'll have another fruitless morning of it using old tokens and not being able to renew them. I'm sure this is something I just don't understand, but I'd rather not go to storing them in a local file if I don't have to. The first answer that comes up on here reveals that others have similar issues and generally resort either to their own storage or the registry, but it is an 11-year-old answer. I'm using VS 2019, if that makes any difference.

This is the code I use to store the new token away, if it helps:

```
My.Settings.RefreshToken = newToken ' this is returned in the refresh request
My.Settings.Save
```

When my code opens, it loads the settings in a similar way:

```
accessToken = My.Settings.AccessToken
refreshToken = My.Settings.RefreshToken
tokenExpires = My.Settings.Expiry
```

Even if I edit my app.exe.config file to contain "*" in the expiry field, it is still somehow finding the expiry date/time from the previous time the service successfully ran. So it clearly isn't retrieving the information from that file any more.

Comment: My apologies, I don't have enough experience with this stuff to know that there is more than one way to do it. I will edit the post to include the code.

Comment: I’m not really 100% sure you’re heading down the right approach here.  I’m pretty sure that is not how oauth is really supposed to be used.  Your supposed to authenticate with the oAuth endpoint, which returns you an access and refresh token.  Storing these tokens at all just seems a little off

Comment: I only store them so that if the service restarts (for example a machine reboot) it will be attempting to refresh the latest token. If I only have the very first refresh token stored in settings (or anywhere else), it will reject that because it's already been superseded. In fact that's what is happening here - because I am not putting the "new" token pair into the correct location, it's attempting to connect with an old token pair and having it rejected.

Comment: Leaving aside the OAuth usage issue, though, the same applies to any setting that I may need to update - the problem I'm having is trying to find where these are being stored once the service code itself starts writing back to the settings.

Comment: What Profile is your Service using? --   Check in `Drive:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData` or `Drive:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData`

Comment: @Jimi thank you for that - I have found a user.config file in the SysWOW64 tree that does appear to be dated back in May, which I suspect is the active config setting. I was looking in /users for the user.config file.

Comment: Yes, to confirm, the settings that are updated by the service are stored in the latter location. I think that for a clean install, editing app.exe.config will be OK, it's causing trouble on my development machine because it has run before. I'm not sure of the correct way to mark this as "answered" now.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question (and accept it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this off, the comment by @Jimi earlier on held the key. The settings that are updated by the service are stored in a file called user.config which in my case is in c:\windows\syswow64\config\systemprofile\appdata and then my application name.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to do that, but it's another 23 hours before it allows me.